# Web Scraping - No content displayed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to fetch the stock of a company specified by a user by taking the input. I am using requests to get the source code and BeautifulSoup to scrape. I am fetching the data from *google.com*. I am trying the fetch only the last stock price (806.93 in the picture). When I run my script, it prints none. None of the data is being fetched. What am I missing ?

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

company = raw_input("Enter the company name:")

URL = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-AKmV6eqC-LH8AfRqb_4Aw#newwindow=1&safe=off&q="+company+"+stock"

request = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"lxml")

code = soup.find('span',{'class':'_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l','data-symbol':'GOOGL'})
print code.contents[0]
```

The source code of the page looks like this :

[image: The source code]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that source is from inspecting the element, not the actual source.  A couple of suggestions.  Use google finance to get rid of some noise - **https://www.google.com/finance?q=googl** would be the URL.  On that page there is a section that looks like this:

```
<div class=g-unit>
<div id=market-data-div class="id-market-data-div nwp g-floatfix">
<div id=price-panel class="id-price-panel goog-inline-block">
<div>
<span class="pr">
<span id="ref_694653_l">806.93</span>
</span>
<div class="id-price-change nwp">
<span class="ch bld"><span class="chg" id="ref_694653_c">+9.68</span>
<span class="chg" id="ref_694653_cp">(1.21%)</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

You should be able to pull the number out of that.

Comment: I am able to fetch data from the above mentioned website. But whatever I try to fetch from the main google page isn't working, be it currency conversion, stocks or sports scores. I don't find 806.93 in page source code but displays when inspecting the element (Google main page). Why is this happening with google.com alone?

Answer (score 1):

I went to 
    https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-AKmV6eqC-LH8AfRqb_4Aw#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=+google+stock 
, did a right click and "View Page Source" but did not see the code that you screenshotted.

Then I typed out a section of your code screenshot and created a BeautifulSoup object with it and then ran your find on it:

```
test_screenshot = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_F0c" data-tmid="/m/07zln7n"><span class="_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l" data-symbol="GOOGL" data-tmid="/m/07zln7n" data-value="806.93">806.93.</span> = $0<span class ="_hgj">USD</span>')

test_screenshot.find('span',{'class':'_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l','data-symbol':'GOOGL'})`
```

Which will output what you want:
    `<span class="_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l" data-symbol="GOOGL" data-tmid="/m/07zln7n" data-value="806.93">806.93.</span>`

This means that the code you are getting is not the code you expect to get.

I suggest using the google finance page:
`https://www.google.com/finance?q=google` (replace 'google' with what you want to search), which will give you wnat you are looking for:

```
request = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"lxml")
code = soup.find("span",{'class':'pr'})
print code.contents
```

Will give you 
    `[u'\n', <span id="ref_694653_l">806.93</span>, u'\n']`.

In general, scraping Google search results can get really nasty, so try to avoid it if you can.

You might also want to look into [Yahoo Finance Python API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4).

Comment: Yeah..its getting nasty. Not able to fetch any data be it anything from google.com. The page source code and inspecting codes are different on all cases. Why is this happening with google main page alone and not with the others? Is the Javascript modifying the source html code?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
# two selectors which will handle two layouts
current_price = soup.select_one('.wT3VGc, .XcVN5d').text
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

It might be because there's no [`user-agent` specified in your request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

The default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you received a different HTML with different selectors and elements, and some sort of an error. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}
response = requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Multiple-Answer-Box#stock_answerbox.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0'

params = {
  'q': 'alphabet inc class a stock',
  'gl': 'us'
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


# two selectors which will handle two layouts
current_price = soup.select_one('.wT3VGc, .XcVN5d').text
print(current_price)

# 2,816.00
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want fast rather than figuring out why certain things don't work as expected and then to maintain it over time.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "alphabet inc class a stock",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

current_price = results['answer_box']['price']
print(current_price)

# 2,816.00
```

P.S - I wrote an in-depth blog post about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.